# Tiling texture doesn't repeat, even though wrap mode is set to repeat

Tags: unity, textures

For some reason, my floor tiling (set to 100 x 100) only shows on one corner of the plane. Past that corner, it just stretches out to the sides and leaves the middle one solid colour:

[image: Screenshot of tiles]

Here is how I've imported the texture (which was [created by Jimmy Vegas](https://jvunity.weebly.com/):

[image: Texture import screenshot]

And my material settings look like this:

[image: Material inspector screenshot]

Comment: Are you using 9-slicing to do tiling?

Comment: @AlexF I'm pretty new to this what does that mean.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/9SliceSprites.html

Comment: @AlexF no im just using a material. it's 3D

Comment: Which material? We can't help you figure out the problem if we don't know what tools you're using. You can use the edit button under your question to add information.

Comment: @AlexF there is more info now

Comment: How have you set up the texture coordinates on your mesh?

Comment: @DMGregory I haven't changed anything.

Comment: You haven't changed anything from what starting point? Walk us through the full set of steps we'd need to follow to reproduce this problem in a brand new empty project.

Comment: @DMGregory I have tried that however it's normal in a new project, I don't know how it happened. It just happened one day.

Comment: @DMGregory I fixed it, I just simply re installed the texture and deleted the material and started it all over again and now it looks like it should

Comment: Sounds great! Post that solution as an Answer so it can help other devs who run into similar problems. :)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it, I just simply re installed the texture and deleted the material and started it all over again and now it looks like it should!